# How to use an FTP server as backup space for Windows Server 2012

Tags: backup, ftp, windows-server-2012, service

I wanted to use an FTP location as backup for scheduled Windows Server 2012 Backup.

I can't make it work because Windows refuses to accept the network location as drive. Even with "FTPUse" (socket error appeared, no idea why...) or "WebDrive" it didn't work out.

Many people suggested that WebDrive would be a nice solution. I was able to assign a drive letter to the FTP location and it appeared like that in Windows Explorer. But the Backup application of the server didn't let me pick it when I wanted to use "Back up to a volume" or "Back up to a shared network folder".

Any idea how I could get a workaround?

Comment: Did you test the ftp location/connection manually from your windows Server 2012? The socket error may be due to plain ftp connection error.

Comment: Yes. I tested ftp user@ip and this worked. On other side, FTPUse user@ip gave me a socket error. The only thing I know is that this FTP server is only available from this very IP, but FTPUse should also use a direct connection, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying again with Webdrive and reading their full documentation, I found a solution! I figured out that Windows only accepts the "Universal Naming Convention path" of backup storages. Webdrive creates such a path and it always is named like

```
\\Webdrive\YourNameOfFTPSite
```

Unfortunately, Windows does still not let me make the backup because it needs to be on an NTFS drive and my backup location is running on a Linux server. But this is another issue...

Answer (score 0):

Not really a work around but Symantec System Recovery supports an FTP location as a destination for backups.  There is a free trial available [at the Symantec site](http://www.symantec.com/system-recovery-server-edition)

Comment: Have you tried it on the new Windows Backup (of Server 2012)? WebDrive was also supposed to work but didn't for a weird reason